# TypeError: unbound method must be called with instance as first argument (got int instance instead) in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 3 the following set of codes works, I wonder why in python 2.7 it gives me a TypeError: unbound method add() must be called with calc instance as first argument(got int instance instead)? how do I resolve this in Python 2.7?

```
class calc:
    def add(x,y):
        answer = x + y
        print(answer)

    def sub(x,y):
        answer = x - y
        print(answer)

    def mult(x,y):
        answer = x * y
        print(answer)

    def div(x,y):
        answer = x / y
        print(answer)

calc.add(5, 7)
```

Comment: You aren't showing all your code. This runs perfectly fine in Python 2.7. Plus your error is referencing code that you are not showing.

Comment: @idjaw, Sorry! I've fixed that up now! cheers

Comment: Next question. Do you want those methods inside `calc` to be *instance methods*? Because you are now not treating them as such.

Comment: @idjaw, yes that is the idea

Comment: To rephrase the question from @idjaw -- Why do you have a class here in the first place?  None of the methods use `self` and the way you are calling it, it makes it seem unlikely that they are meant to ... What benefit do you get by using a class instead of just providing a bunch of module-level functions?

Comment: @mgilson, sorry I am actually a newbie, I saw this set of codes from a udemy course titled "Python Programming for Beginners" and this was taken from lecture 17 titled "Classes"....To be honest I do also think this is a bad practice from my experience with Java OOP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `staticmethod` for python2.7 in your case

```
class calc:

    @staticmethod
    def add(x,y):
        answer = x + y
        print(answer)

#call staticmethod add directly 
#without declaring instance and accessing class variables
calc.add(5,7)
```

Or, Use `instance method` if you need to call other instance methods or use anything inside class

```
class calc:

    def add(self,x,y):
        print(self._add(x,y)) #call another instance method _add
    def _add(self,x,y):
        return x+y

#declare instance
c = calc()
#call instance method add
c.add(5,7)
```

Additionally, Use `classmethod` if you need to use class variables but without declaring instance

```
class calc:

    some_val = 1

    @classmethod
    def add_plus_one(cls,x,y):
        answer = x + y + cls.some_val #access class variable
        print(answer)

#call classmethod add_plus_one dircetly
#without declaring instance but accessing class variables
calc.add_plus_one(5,7)
```

Answer (score 4):

It *looks* like you are trying to implement a class with a whole bunch of static functions.  You *can* do that, but there really is no need.  Unlike other languages, python does not require classes to function.  You can define your methods *without the class*:

```
def add(x, y):
    answer = x + y
    print(answer)

add(5, 7)
```

Because of the way importing works in python, the fundamental unit of namespace is the *module*, not the *class*.

```
from module import some_class  # works.
from module import submodule  # works.
from module.some_class import method  # doesn't work
```

So, you'll always be better off using modules as they were intended and not using classes as modules :-).