# socket.settimeout() isn't working in Python 2.7 (Port Scanner)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I tried coding a small port scanner but thought I could fix the slow scanning by setting a timeout on closed ports... But that isn't working in this case.

This is my function for scanning the port:

```py
def connHost(THost, TPort, output=None):
    try:
        socket.settimeout(3)
        socket.connect((THost,TPort))
        print colored('   [+]%d/tcp open', 'green') %TPort

        if output != None:
            file = open(output, 'a')        
            file.write("[+]Port: %d is open\n" %TPort) 
            file.close()
    except:
        print colored('   [-]%d/tcp close', 'red') %TPort
    finally:
        socket.close()
```

By the way, the `output` variable has no problem, its a feature to output the open ports in a newly created file.

So whenever I run the script, it shows me this error:
[image: Error socket.settimeout(3)]

If you want to view the full source, here is a link to my laggy scanner (without setting timeout feature): [Port Scanner](https://github.com/belikeParamjot/3L3Y3.git)

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: College Project, and python 2.7 is my optional language while I pursue website designing as my main course

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701142/typeerror-unbound-method-must-be-called-with-instance-as-first-argument-got-in/40701173

Comment: @gmdev Nthng changed with any of the 3 methods

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look into the source code on GitHub, you aren't using a class - that is why the methods I linked in the comments did not work.

You are most likely getting this error because you are calling `settimeout()` on a *reference* and not an *instance* - you never instantiate the variable "socket"

```
s = # initialize socket here
s.settimeout(3)
```

You can find more information on `bound` and `unbound` methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473184/unbound-method-f-must-be-called-with-fibo-instance-as-first-argument-got-cla)

Another note: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules), it is generally not conventional to import an entire module using `*` as

> "...it introduces an unknown set of names into the interpreter, possibly hiding some things you have already defined."

Comment: no i did create a reference in the final upload i made... but when I added timeout, with reference it gave me more error... So I directly called socket on each command... also, I used this technique after reading an answer from stackoverflow. So, am pretty much sure about it.

Comment: Okay, just curious - the error isn't caught by the `try except`?

Comment: No, it did... The screenshot I took is after removing the try except blocks... Just to debug and see where it is catching error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that throws the error including the code where you instantiate the socket?